# Why am I getting model not found error when it already exists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

I've created a model "library.book.category" and included its model file in **init**.py as well. It created its table in Postgres but when I update my module from odoo apps I get this error: **Model not found: library.book.category**.
I also checked this model from settings -> technical -> models, it has been created but I'm still getting this error.

**library_book_categ.py**

```
from odoo import models, fields, api


class BookCategory(models.Model):
    _name = 'library.book.category'
    _parent_store = True
    _parent_name = "parent_id"

    name = fields.Char('Category')
    parent_path = fields.Char(index=True)
    parent_id = fields.Many2one(
        'library.book.category',
        string='Parent Category',
        ondelete='restrict',
        index=True
    )
    child_ids = fields.One2many(
        'library.book.category',
        'parent_id',
        string='Child Categories'
    )

    @api.constrains('parent_id')
    def _check_hierarchy(self):
        if not self._check_recursion():
            raise models.ValidationError(
                'Error! You cannot create recursive categories.'
            )
```

****init**.py**

```
from . import library_book_categ
from . import library_book
```

**views.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>

    <record id="library_book_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Library Book Form</field>
        <field name="model">library.book</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form>
                <group>
                    <group>
                        <field name="name"/>
                        <field name="author_ids" widget="many2many_tags"/>
                        <field name="publisher_id"/>
<!--                        <field name="category_id"/>-->
                        <field name="state"/>
                        <field name="pages"/>
                        <field name="notes"/>
                        <field name="cost_price"/>
                    </group>
                    <group>
                        <field name="short_name"/>
                        <field name="date_release"/>
                        <field name="date_updated"/>
                        <field name="cover" widget="image" class="oe_avatar"/>
                        <field name="reader_rating"/>
                        <field name="currency_id"/>
                        <field name="retail_price"/>
                    </group>
                </group>
                <group>
                    <field name="description"/>
                </group>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="book_category_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Book Category Form</field>
        <field name="model">library.book.category</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form>
                <group>
                    <group>
                        <field name="name"/>
                        <field name="parent_id"/>
                        <field name="parent_path"/>
                        <field name="child_ids"/>
                    </group>
                </group>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="library_book_view_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Library Book List</field>
        <field name="model">library.book</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree>
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="date_release"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="book_category_view_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Book Category List</field>
        <field name="model">library.book.category</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree>
                <field name="id"/>
                <field name="name"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="library_book_view_search" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Library Book Search</field>
        <field name="model">library.book</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search>
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="author_ids"/>
                <filter string="No Authors"
                        name="without_author"
                        domain="[('author_ids','=',False)]"/>
            </search>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id='library_book_action' model='ir.actions.act_window'>
        <field name="name">Library Books</field>
        <field name="res_model">library.book</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>

    <record id='book_category_action' model='ir.actions.act_window'>
        <field name="name">Book Categories</field>
        <field name="res_model">library.book.category</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem name="My Library" id="library_base_menu" />
    <menuitem name="Books" id="library_book_menu" parent="library_base_menu" action="library_book_action"/>
    <menuitem name="Categories" id="book_category_menu" parent="library_base_menu" action="book_category_action"/>

</odoo>
```

Comment: May be the error comes from another module where you inherited this model and forget to put dependency? just recheck step by step you will find what you did wrong

Comment: There's no other custom module in my project.

Comment: Have you added the access rights to your model ?

Access rights are defined as records of the model ir.model.access. Each access right is associated to a model, a group (or no group for global access), and a set of permissions: read, write, create, unlink. Such access rights are usually created by a CSV file named after its model: ir.model.access.csv.
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/howtos/backend.html?highlight=model%20access

Comment: Problem solved. Sorry, it was my bad. model file was in the wrong directory.